# Cannot create a TaxonomyField programmatically

Tags: 2013, development, taxonomy

I am trying to create a TaxonomyField programmatically and add it to a `list`. This is my code

```
TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(site);
TermStore termStore = session.DefaultKeywordsTermStore;

Group termGroup = termStore.Groups[Const.TAXONOMY_MA_TERMGROUP_NAME];
string termSetX = "myTermSet";

TermSet termSet = termGroup.TermSets[termSetX];

try
{
    if (web.Fields.TryGetFieldByStaticName(t) == null)
    {
        TaxonomyField taxField = web.Fields.CreateNewField("TaxonomyFieldType", t) as TaxonomyField;

        taxField.SspId = termSet.TermStore.Id;
        taxField.Group = termGroup.Name;
        taxField.TermSetId = termSet.Id;
        taxField.AllowMultipleValues = true;
        taxField.TargetTemplate = string.Empty;
        taxField.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;
        taxField.Update();

        web.Fields.Add(taxField);
        web.Update();

        newsList.Fields.Add(taxField);
        //newsListView.ViewFields.Add(t);
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
}
```

But the last line

```
web.Fields.Add(taxField)
```

throws an error

> Key cannot be null.

Any idea what this could be?

Comment: Have you checked that your TermStore and TermSet ID exists? You should open a taxonomySession and request those values directly from there.

Comment: I updated my code and i am 100% sure that TermSet and TermGroup exist.

Comment: Can you try to change the DefaultKeywordsTermStore to DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore.
The one you are using is just for Enterprise Keywords but not for all other term sets.

Comment: This is the correct TermStore. It is filled centrally with Masterdata. I am using it already on several custom application pages where it works fine. I am also able to create manually a list and add a managed metadata column and bind it to this TermStore. But i am not able to programmatically add a TaxonomyField to a list.

Comment: Had a similar issues a couple of times with the default key word term store. I currently always try to find a matching Term Set in all Term stores.

Comment: But my code gives returns me a valid TermSet when i debug the code.

Comment: Is the term set available for tagging? This might cause this issue too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I think `web.Update();` is not needed. But probably not related to your problem.
2. Here's how I've already done it. Note I update field properties only after adding it to the site columns collection (`web.Fields.Add` called before `field.Update()`):

```
if (!web.AvailableFields.ContainsField(fieldInternalName))  
{  
   field = web.Fields.CreateNewField("TaxonomyFieldType", fieldInternalName) as TaxonomyField;  
   web.Fields.Add(field);  
}  

field = web.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldInternalName) as TaxonomyField;  
field.Title = "Field display Name";  
field.Description = "Description";  
field.Required = true;  
field.Group = "CustomGroup";  
field.AllowMultipleValues = true;  
field.IsPathRendered = true;  
field.Update();  

TaxonomySession session = new TaxonomySession(web.Site);  

// get the default metadata service application      
TermStore termStore = session.DefaultSiteCollectionTermStore;  
Group group = null;  
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(termGroupName))  
   group = termStore.GetSiteCollectionGroup(web.Site);  
else  
   group = termStore.Groups.GetByName(termGroupName);  
TermSet termSet = group.TermSets.GetByName(termSetName);  

field.SspId = termSet.TermStore.Id;  
field.TermSetId = termSet.Id;  
field.TargetTemplate = string.Empty;  
field.AnchorId = Guid.Empty;  
field.Update();
```